# Summarizing & counting large data sets and getting E_RUNAWAY_QUERY Error - "exceeded the memory budget"

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am running a relatively heavy query that is consistently failing with this error

```
Partial query failure: Runaway query (E_RUNAWAY_QUERY). (message: 'Aggregation over string column exceeded the memory budget of 8GB during evaluation (see https://aka.ms/kustoquerylimits)
```

The query is spread across multiple clusters and indeed aggregates over a single, medium length (~10-200 chars), column. The aggregation method is a counter for each unique value of this column.  This basically the only thing I run in this query and I can't avoid aggregating this field. It is divided into 3 aggregating steps:

```
| summarize hint.strategy=shuffle  count() by <string_field>
| sort by count_
| limit 100
```

Is there a work around for this issue to be able to exceed the 8GB limit? or any ideas I haven't tried?

Things I tried in order fix it (As written here https://aka.ms/kustoquerylimits) :

1. set maxmemoryconsumptionperiterator=108719476736;
2. adding shuffle - `summarize hint.strategy=shuffle  count() by <string_field>`
3. Ommitting some of the results - this is not ideal and only when I reached approximately 20% of the results over a timespan of 2 days it worked. I would like to see more reliable results though for a longer time span; `| where rand() < 0.2`

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the [`top-hitters` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tophittersoperator) instead